# write an existing r studio project to github

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

I'm totally new to github and need to push an existing R studio project and all files to a github repository.  I originally created the project under source control but I don't understand how to write it to my github account or to a specific repository.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't really RStudio specific. You just need something like [this guide](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line), and if you already have things committed in your local git repo you can probably skip to step 7/8

Comment: I suggest you peruse this [book](https://happygitwithr.com/) as well as the [usethis](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis) package.

Comment: as a newbie you may consider using https://desktop.github.com/ that should semplify your workflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+tutorial